# Php code in xml.php file

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I'm working on xml.php file structured below:

```html
<?php
    $xmlstr = <<<'XML'
    <?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>

<root>
  <subroot>
    <![CDATA[

... some php code here ...

            ]]>
  </subroot>
</root>

    XML;
    ?>
```

I want to add the below php code between CDATA so that we can call it later through index.html file:

```html
        <?php 
          include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'xml.php';  
          $template = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 
          echo $articles->article[0]->name; 
        ?>
```

However, it doesn't work like this and have run out of ideas on how can we make it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: that's not a valid xml, you need `<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?><root><![CDATA]]></root>`

Comment: I think that your observation is correct and I have just include cdata between subroot element which is part of the root element. And according to akrys suggestion I change the last line of the code from XML to 'XML'.

Answer (score 2):

1. Problem:

Your XML string needs an element you can address. At least a root element should be defined in your XML string. Usually it's called `root`.

2. Problem

Your XML is defined in *heredocs*, which behaves like a string in double quotes. This means all variables are parsed, while the string is stored into `$xmlstr`.

So, you wont't get valid source code, after storing it to `$xmlstr`.

You'll need to define this single quotes. Then your variables aren't parsed and replaced. That can be done using *nowdoc* (avaliable as of PHP 5.3). You'll just have to add two single quote signs (`<<<'XML'` instead of `<<<XML`)

So, after all, your `xml.php` code (as I understand you) would look like this:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<'XML'
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<root>
<![CDATA[
    <?php 
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'xml.php';  
    $template = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 
    echo $articles->article[0]->name; 
    ?>
]]>
</root>
XML;


$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
print (string)$x; //prints the code as it is defined in $xmlstr
```

Details to *heredoc* and *nowdoc* can be found here:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc